# whyIPersistedGrantStore does not work with SQL storage?

Tags: sql, identityserver4

I was following the documentation tutorial and the topic "Using EntityFramework Core for configuration data" indicates that the configurations can be stored in the base, but the problem is that following the documentation the only thing that works for me are the configurations of client, scope, user.

the Storage of the PersistedGrant when the application is deployed, is still handled in memory

How do I make the IPersistedGrantStore not to be handled in memory??

If someone owns in a git repository an implementation of the IPersistedGrantStore that can facilitate me would be very helpful.